# How to align Wave Texture to the curve

Tags: texturing

I'm making waving texture, but the band is not aligned with the direction of the curve,like this,

[image]

What I want to achieve is the band should be directed by the curve direction as the red line shows, but how to setup properly, I've tried different texture coordinate all the same result.

Edit:My shader, but I do not see any UV map after press "U" on my keyboard

[image]

Edit2:I've tried the direction is all right but it gave me un-evenly bands, do you know why this is happening,thanks.

[image]

Comment: People need to see your wireframe, UV map, nodes, and modifiers to help.

Comment: The un-evenness comes from the fact that your control points are not spaced evenly. I don't know if you can make the uvs follow the "real" length though

Answer (score 3):

You don't tell a lot about your node setup, but try the *Generated* or the *UV* output socket of the *Texture Coordinate* node:

[image]

Comment: Sorry for lack of information, but the shape is made of a curve and set depth to0.5m, the elbow by extruding the vertex, I need to get home to show all info.

Comment: Curve objects automatically have a set of UVs. You may need to tweak the mapping node to fit the wave texture though

Comment: I've added my screen shot

Comment: @Gorgious Hi I've used your method it worked but the bands are not spreading evenly, I've added another screen shot

Comment: maybe share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/